# Heatmap, radar charts in Taipy

Tags: user-interface, charts, taipy

Just getting started with Taipy and really like the way I’ve been able to quickly set up a nice dashboard for my data project. I’d like to add a few other graphics, including a heatmap, and a radar chart.

How can I get access to some graphics that don’t seem to be available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade Taipy to the latest version as these types are now available.

[Radar charts](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/charts/radar/) and [heatmaps](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/charts/heatmap/) are both accessible as well as a lot more charts. [This documentation](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/chart/) shows you examples of Taipy charts with different types.